# ExtJS: better way to pass parameter to grid from another page

Tags: extjs

What is better way to pass some parameters(mbe post, get, cookie?) from one page to another to extjs script(second is the simple grid with json store)?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better than what?

I use this function to get values from url string

```
Ext.ns('MyNamespace');
MyNamespace.get = function(key) {
  var params = Ext.urlDecode(window.location.search.substring(1));
  return params[key] || null;
}

//example usage
var ID = MyNamespace.get('ID');
```

I use it rarely however. Most of my components use `Ext.Ajax.request()` calls to get any parameters straight from the server.